# Error running drush on a particular Drupal website

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drush

I had drush working on my website, but recently ive started seeing an error whenever I am inside of the website root.

`There was a problem acquiring the API key, please contact the site administrator.`

I get this error when running any drush commands on the drupal website, however drush works fine for the other websites that are hosted on the same server.

Is there quick fix for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try to open two instance of your terminal. In the first one, type this command to see logs `drush ws --tail` and run the command which throw your error in the second. You first need to know which module is causing this error by reading logs in the first terminal before debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Turned out it was the Omega theme after it had been updated!  If you post that as an answer, I can accept it and give you the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open two instance of your terminal. In the first one, type this command to see logs `drush ws --tail` and run the command which throw your error in the second. You first need to know which module is causing this error by reading logs in the first terminal before debugging.